# How can I instantiate a generic Scala type from a generic Java type?

Tags: java, scala, generics

I have a Scala class Foo:

```
case class Foo[T](obj: T)
```

I want to create an instance of class Foo in Java class Bar:

```
public class Bar<T> {
    private final Foo<T> _foo;
    public Bar(T obj) {
        this._foo = Foo.apply((T) toScala(obj));
    }
}
```

toScala is able to create the appropriate Scala type, and this code works if T is a concrete type. With generic type T, I get the error "java: cannot find symbol: method apply(T)". Can I use a generic type in this way?

Comment: what's `toScala`? Just `new Foo(obj)` should work.